# How to let googlemail send an automatic mail -from- a secondary mail adress?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'd like to send a mail with GoogleScript - not from my main-Gmailaccount, but from a secondary mail account, which is setup correctly in the main Gmail account.
I can send emails from the secondary mail account manually in Gmail, so that works fine. So to make it clear again:  it shouldn't send as abc@gmail.com, but abc@domainname.com)

In G-Script I use `MailApp.sendEmail({` - in the documentary it seems that there are just options to set the name of the sender and set the replyTo adress. If I do this the abc@gmail.com still appears as the sender. Is there a way to change the sender itself?

Documentary: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Comment: You'd have to run the script as that secondary email address for it to be the actual sending email account afaik.

Answer (score 0):

If your secondary email is setup as an alias of your email account it is possible. The specification mention:

> from: the address that the email should be sent from, which must be
>   one of the values returned by getAliases()

When you execute getAliases(), do you see your alias?

```
 // Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.
 var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
 Logger.log(aliases);
 if (aliases.length > 0) {
   GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0]});
 } else {
   GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'No aliases found', 'You have no aliases.');
 }
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases()